# std::regex_replace to replace multiple combinations

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to utilize the std::regex_replace to replace a few combinations of characters with other characters. However, each set of characters has a different set of characters I would like to replace it with (it depends on the character).
I thought about using a map , but that will not work as I do not have access to the character being replaced (as seen in the code). Any idea how to cover all replacement cases in one regex_replace statement (or perhaps a better approach) ?
Current Code:

```
std::regex r(" c|ph|th|ea|c|w");
    map<string, string> comb{
        {" c", "k"},
        { "ph", "f" },  
        { "th", "z" },
        { "ea", "e" },
        { "c", "s" },
        { "w", "v" }
    };
line = std::regex_replace(line, r, comb[r]);
```

Comment: `{" c", "k"},` `{ "c", "s" },` So... what does "c" get replaced with here?

Comment: @NicolBolas what i 'want' is to replace the c at the beginning of a word with k and any other c with s.

Comment: "*at the beginning of a word*" Words don't always begin with spaces. Also, "kello"is probably not the best spelling of that word.

Comment: well, my assumption is that words are preceded with an empty space, unless its the first word. i do not get your comment about the 'kello' but sure @NicolBolas

Comment: The word "cello" is pronounced with a "ch" sound, which neither "k" nor "s" sounds like..

Comment: I don't know how that is relevant to my question.. If you do not know the answer you do not have to comment about the program's logical functionality as I have not mentioned it.. @NicolBolas

Comment: Unfortunately, `std::regex_replace` (or anything else in the C++ standard library) doesn't accept a callback for formatting the replacement. There's no mechanism to make a replacement string depend on the match, beyond literally substituting the match into a fixed format string with placeholders. For anything more complex, you'd need to have a loop that enumerates all matches (e.g. with `std::regex_iterator`) and builds a replacement string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can hack together our own custom `regex_replace` using a `regex_iterator` and your map:

### [Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hEzn84dr9)

First, let's write function that accepts a `std::map<string, string>` and returns a `regex` that is just an alternation `|` between the keys. This will let us keep a strong association between the map and the resulting regex.

```
std::regex regex_from_map(const std::map<std::string, std::string>& map)
{
    std::string pattern_str = "(";
    auto it = map.begin();
    if (it != map.end())
    {
        pattern_str += it->first;
        for(++it; it != map.end(); ++it)
            pattern_str += "|" + it->first;
    }
    pattern_str += ")";
    return std::regex(pattern_str);
}
```

Next, let's write a function that accepts the text to be matched and your replacement map, then iterates over each match and finds the appropriate replacement to build the result string:

```
std::string custom_regex_replace(const std::string& text,
    const std::map<std::string, std::string>& replacement_map)
{
    auto regex = regex_from_map(replacement_map);
    std::string result;
    std::sregex_iterator it(text.begin(), text.end(), regex);
    std::sregex_iterator end;

    size_t last_pos = 0;
    for (; it != end; ++it) {
        result += text.substr(last_pos, it->position() - last_pos);
        result += replacement_map.at(it->str());
        last_pos = it->position() + it->length();
    }
    result += text.substr(last_pos, text.size() - last_pos);

    return result;
}
```

Finally, calling our custom replacement function:

```
int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> replacement_map = 
    {   {" c", "k"},
        { "ph", "f" },  
        { "th", "z" },
        { "ea", "e" },
        { "c", "s" },
        { "w", "v" }
    };

    std::string text = "each word pheels new, cnow?";
    std::string new_text = custom_regex_replace(text, replacement_map);
    std::cout << new_text << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

> "each word pheels new, cnow?"

Output:

> "esh vord feels nev,knov?"

(Note that `" c"` is replace with `"k"`, so the space after the comma was deleted)